# Creating composite foreign key constraint

Tags: t-sql, foreign-keys, constraints, composite-key

I am trying to create a composite foreign key relationship/constraint.  All tables are empty.  I have this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChemSampleValueTest](
    [SampleNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParameterID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [numeric](18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [Accuracy] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ResultGroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [QAState] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_SampleValueTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [SampleNumber] ASC,
        [ParameterID] ASC,
        [ResultGroupID] ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChemSampleValueEventLinkTest](
    [Event] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SampleNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ResultGroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParameterID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [QAState] [nvarchar](32) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and I want to link them like this:

```sql
alter table [ChemSampleValueEventLinkTest] add 
    constraint FK_ChemSampleValueEvent_ChemSampleValue_test
    foreign key ([SampleNumber], [ResultGroupID], [ParameterID]) 
    references ChemSampleValueTest ([SampleNumber], [ResultGroupID], [ParameterID])
```

As far as I can tell all column types are the same, but it keeps on saying

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 
>   'ChemSampleValueTest' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key
>   'FK_ChemSampleValueEvent_ChemSampleValue_test'.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There are a few similar questions dotted around (mostly about constraint violations), but I couldn't find anything that helped me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you need to have your FK/references list in the same order they appear in the PK definition.

This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChemSampleValueTest](
    [SampleNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParameterID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [numeric](18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [Accuracy] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ResultGroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [QAState] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_SampleValueTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [SampleNumber] ASC,
        [ParameterID] ASC,
        [ResultGroupID] ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChemSampleValueEventLinkTest](
    [Event] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SampleNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ResultGroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParameterID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [QAState] [nvarchar](32) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

alter table [ChemSampleValueEventLinkTest] add 
    constraint FK_ChemSampleValueEvent_ChemSampleValue_test
    foreign key ([SampleNumber], [ParameterID], [ResultGroupID]) 
    references ChemSampleValueTest ([SampleNumber], [ParameterID], [ResultGroupID])
```

Comment: You are correct.  Thinking about it, that makes sense.  Composite foreign keys.  Mind-bending, but starting to make sense.  Thanks for your help mate.