# Alter Table Add Constraint vs Alter Table Add Check Constraint

Tags: sql-server

I'm experiencing a strange issue in SSMS.

My table design makes heavy use of composite-keys to enforce strict and robust referential integrity across all transitive relations - at a cost of violating BCNF, but in practice it's proving quite handy, especially with Entity Framework's automatic Navigation Properties (related to this question I posted earlier: [How can I enforce second-degree relationships without composite keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743526/how-can-i-enforce-second-degree-relationships-without-composite-keys) ).

Anyway, I'm having issues with adding Foreign Key relationships using SSMS 2014's diagram editor.

Here's a simplified example of my problem:

```
CREATE TABLE Tenants (
    TenantId bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE Shops (
    TenantId bigint, -- Is a FOREIGN KEY( Tenants REFERENCES TenantId )
    ShopId   bigint IDENTITY(1,1)

    PRIMARY KEY( TenantId, ShopId )
)

CREATE TABLE Job (
    TenantId bigint, -- Is a FOREIGN KEY( Tenants REFERENCES TenantId )
    ShopId   bigint, -- Is a FOREIGN KEY( Shops REFERENCES TenantId )
    JobId    bigint IDENTITY(1,1)

    PRIMARY KEY( TenantId, ShopId, JobId )
)
```

I have many tables with columns like these, and using the Diagram Editor to create relationships with referential integrity for composite keys works fine (you simply ctrl+click each composite FK column, then drag on to the primary-key table, and click OK, and that's it.

However with some times, it fails. For example, if I select `TenantId` and `ShopId` in `Jobs` and drag them on to the `Shops` table, it gives me this error:

> The columns in table 'Shops' do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint.

...even though those two columns **are** the primary-key of the `Shops` table!

I got SSMS to generate the SQL for the constraint it was attempting to add, and it gave me this (formatting mine, additional `TRANSACTION` code removed):

```
ALTER TABLE
    dbo.Jobs
ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_Jobs_Shops
FOREIGN KEY
    ( ShopId, TenantId ) REFERENCES dbo.Shops ( ShopId, TenantId )

ON UPDATE
    NO ACTION
ON DELETE
    NO ACTION
```

When I ran it directly, SQL Server gave me this error:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table '`dbo.Shops`' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key '`FK_Jobs_Shops`'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Note that **other tables already had a defined foreign-key relationship to the `Shops` table** - so I wondered what was going on. So I told SSMS to <kbd>Script to CREATE</kbd> the seemingly working constraints - I then renamed things to make it create the constraint I wanted originally (between `Jobs` and `Shops`), and it gave me this **different** output (formatting mine):

```
ALTER TABLE
    [dbo].Jobs WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT
    [FK_Jobs_Shops]
FOREIGN KEY
    ([TenantId], [ShopId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Shops] ([TenantId], [ShopId])
GO

ALTER TABLE
    [dbo].[Jobs]
CHECK CONSTRAINT
    [FK_Jobs_Shops]
GO
```

When I ran this it worked!

Note the differences:

- The addition of `WITH CHECK`
- The lack of `ON UPDATE` / `ON DELETE` statements
- The constraint was effected in two statements, not one.

My questions:

- Have I discovered a bug in SQL Server?
- Is there a semantic difference between the two constraint definition syntaxes?
- Or rather, why does one work but not the other?

Comment: did you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529941/with-check-add-constraint-followed-by-check-constraint-vs-add-constraint , maybe useful

Answer (score 2):

The only significant difference between the two scripts is the order of the foreign key fields / referenced primary key fields.

The failing script uses `(ShopId, TenantId)` which is not the order of the primary key definition:

```
PRIMARY KEY(TenantId, ShopId)
```

Couldn't find a official reference but it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612473/3215527) that you have to specify the FK fields in the same order as in the PK definition.